# Android build error upon upgrading Cordova's camera plugin

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am getting build error after updating cordova camera plugin from **2.1.1** to **2.3.1**.

Version details:

```
cordova version: 6.3.1,
cordova-plugin-camera 2.1.1 "Camera"
```

What I'm doing:

```
cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-camera --save
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera --save
```

I see the **config.xml** file has been updated to:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="~2.3.1" />
```

When I build cordova android build I get the following error:

```
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
warning: string 'menu_settings' has no default translation.

platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\camera\CameraLauncher.java:32:
    error: cannot find symbol

import org.apache.cordova.BuildHelper;
symbol:   class BuildHelper
location: package org.apache.cordova
platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\camera\CameraLauncher.java:140:
    error: cannot find symbol
this.applicationId = (String)
BuildHelper.getBuildConfigValue(cordova.getActivity(), "APPLICATION_ID");
                                  ^
symbol:   variable BuildHelper
location: class CameraLauncher
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or
--debug option to get more log output.
```

Comment: did you tried removing and re-adding android platform once before building it? Hopefully that should resolve the issue

Answer (score 34, accepted):

We solved this by forcing the install of version 1.1.0.

Here's the commands we ran from the CLI:

```
cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-compat --force
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-compat@1.1.0
```

Comment: this one worked for me as well. But I'm using visual studio 2015 cordova tools. I had to go through tough process to remove and adding these plugins. I wrote a blog post on this on my blog. Please follow the bellow link. http://guntucomputerhacks.blogspot.com.au/2017/04/cordova-camera-plugin-version-240.html

Comment: If you are using "Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova" you might need to run the above commands in the "Package Manager Console" and if you get an error saying "Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project" then you just need to change your current working directory by using a DOS command. In my case, I run DIR to figure out which one was my current working directory and then I run CD App to move to the Cordova-based project directory. After this, the solution listed in this answer worked perfectly fine with no errors.

Comment: Worked for me, Thank you!

Comment: Worked for me too. I had installed 1.2.0 version of the compat plugin which seems to give the same error. Then I uninstalled and installed the 1.1.0 and the errors went away. Thx.

Answer (score 20):

I ran into the same problem today. I got it fixed by re-installing the plugin `cordova-plugin-compat`.
Due to the dependencies I used --force.

```
cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-compat --force
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-compat
```

Comment: could you provide me with versions of plugins you are using.

Comment: it's a good practice to keep all plugins up to date, and the SKD tools too

Comment: I installed camera plugin v2.4.0, then my builds failed. Sadly, the above process failed for me (when I did do the above, afterwards I was prompted to install a cordova update).

When I removed the camera 2.4.0 plugin, my builds would work again. 

I will hunt around to see if there is another suggestion/fix.

Answer (score 3):

You should upgrade cordova-plugin-camera to version 1.1

Comment: I am trying to get the latest version of plugin do not want to downgrade the version

Answer (score 3):

I was also getting error from camera plugin 2.3.1. It is because of the dependency on the cordova-plugin-compat to get the application id. Removing cordova-plugin-compat and installing 1.1.0, didn't work for me.

To fix this remove this code from "src/android/CameraLauncher.java":

```
140      -     this.applicationId = (String) BuildHelper.getBuildConfigValue(cordova.getActivity(), "APPLICATION_ID");
141      -     this.applicationId = preferences.getString("applicationId", this.applicationId);
```

and add:

```
140      +     this.applicationId = cordova.getActivity().getPackageName();
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I got the exact same error. This is actually caused by an old version of the cordova-plugin-compat plugin (1.0), by upgrading to version 1.1 (latest), it will work.

Here is what I did,

1. Remove all platforms

   cordova platform remove android

   cordova platform remove ios
2. Remove old plugin and add new

   cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-compat

   cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-compat
3. Add all platforms back

   cordova platform add android

   cordova platform add ios
4. Re-compile and everything works!

Answer (score 0):

I have made changes to the method below.

```
// intiatiate you action accordingly
if (action.equals("takePicture")) {
            this.srcType = CAMERA;
            this.destType = FILE_URI;
            this.saveToPhotoAlbum = false;
            this.targetHeight = 0;
            this.targetWidth = 0;
            this.encodingType = JPEG;
            this.mediaType = PICTURE;
            this.mQuality = 50;

            //
            this.destType = args.getInt(1);
            this.srcType = args.getInt(2);
            this.mQuality = args.getInt(0);
            this.targetWidth = args.getInt(3);
            this.targetHeight = args.getInt(4);
            this.encodingType = args.getInt(5);
            this.mediaType = args.getInt(6);
            this.allowEdit = args.getBoolean(7);
            this.correctOrientation = args.getBoolean(8);
            this.saveToPhotoAlbum = args.getBoolean(9);

            // If the user specifies a 0 or smaller width/height
            // make it -1 so later comparisons succeed
            if (this.targetWidth < 1) {
                this.targetWidth = -1;
            }
            if (this.targetHeight < 1) {
                this.targetHeight = -1;
            }

              if (this.targetHeight == -1 && this.targetWidth == -1 && this.mQuality == 100 &&
                    !this.correctOrientation && this.encodingType == PNG && this.srcType == CAMERA) {
                this.encodingType = JPEG;
            }

            try {
                if (this.srcType == CAMERA) {
                    this.callTakePicture(destType, encodingType);
                }
                else if ((this.srcType == PHOTOLIBRARY) || (this.srcType == SAVEDPHOTOALBUM)) {
                    // FIXME: Stop always requesting the permission
                    if(!PermissionHelper.hasPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                        PermissionHelper.requestPermission(this, SAVE_TO_ALBUM_SEC, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                    } else {
                        this.getImage(this.srcType, destType, encodingType);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
            {
                callbackContext.error("Illegal Argument Exception");
                PluginResult r = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ERROR);
                callbackContext.sendPluginResult(r);
                return true;
            }

            PluginResult r = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.NO_RESULT);
            r.setKeepCallback(true);
            callbackContext.sendPluginResult(r);

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```